# ALTER TABLE without locking the table?

Tags: sql, mysql, ddl, alter-table

When doing an ALTER TABLE statement in MySQL, the whole table is read-locked (allowing concurrent reads, but prohibiting concurrent writes) for the duration of the statement. If it's a big table, INSERT or UPDATE statements could be blocked for a looooong time. Is there a way to do a "hot alter", like adding a column in such a way that the table is still updatable throughout the process?

Mostly I'm interested in a solution for MySQL but I'd be interested in other RDBMS if MySQL can't do it.

To clarify, my purpose is simply to avoid downtime when a new feature that requires an extra table column is pushed to production. Any database schema *will* change over time, that's just a fact of life. I don't see why we should accept that these changes must inevitably result in downtime; that's just weak.

Comment: Have to wonder how many times you'll be altering the table?

Comment: IMHO, database schema changes are associated with whole new versions - they don't get rolled out sporadically like other changes do. It's inevitably a big deal.

Comment: @AllainLalonde - more than 0 times makes this question legit, especially if downtime in your system would cost lives or lots of money. And at any rate, new software requirements do show up sometimes.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The only other option is to do manually what many RDBMS systems do anyway...
- Create a new table

You can then copy the contents of the old table over a chunk at a time.  Whilst always being cautious of any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on the source table.  (Could be managed by a trigger.  Although this would cause a slow down, it's not a lock...)

Once finished, change the name of the source table, then change the name of the new table.  Preferably in a transaction.

Once finished, recompile any stored procedures, etc that use that table.  The execution plans will likely no longer be valid.

**EDIT:**

Some comments have been made about this limitation being a bit poor.  So I thought I'd put a new perspective on it to show why it's how it is...

- Adding a new field is like changing one field on every row.
- Field Locks would be much harder than Row locks, never mind table locks.
- You're actually changing the physical structure on the disk, every record moves.
- This really is like an UPDATE on the Whole table, but with more impact...

Comment: And have a thorough test plan before swapping. If it fails, start over.

Comment: Column locks are not that big a deal for a columnar database :-).  Also, if you are adding a column, depending on your physical layout this may not require any change to the table data at all -- see the Oracle answer below.

Comment: Managing the synchronization through triggers was a nice idea. I've been using MySQL for so long that I keep forgetting they have triggers now. I've used this technique and now I have a functional hot-alter script. With a progress bar. And it works with MyISAM. Life is good.

Comment: +1 This is literally what SQL Enterprise manager does behind the scenes when you make certain kinds of table changes in the UI. In SQL 2008, they actually added a warning so that the user KNOWS its performing this drastic action.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about foreign keys referencing the tables that are being altered. Wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @MohammadRafayAleem - And AUTOINCREMENT fields, and views, and triggers, etc, etc.  But even so, the *approach* is still workable.

Comment: If you can do this manually, there's no reason the server couldn't do it transparently. It's a shame that the developers of MySQL don't see how obvious a requirement this is.

Answer (score 45):

Percona makes a tool called [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) that allows this to be done.

It essentially makes a copy of the table and modifies the new table. To keep the new table in sync with the original it uses triggers to update. This allows the original table to be accessed while the new table is prepared in the background.

This is similar to Dems suggested method above, but this does so in an automated fashion.

Some of their tools have a learning curve, namely connecting to the database, but once you have that down, they are great tools to have.

Ex:

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD COLUMN c1 INT" D=db,t=numbers_are_friends
```

Comment: It seems the link is broken. I found [this](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) link to be working.

Answer (score 35):

This question from 2009. Now MySQL offers a solution:

**Online DDL (Data Definition Language)**

> A feature that improves the performance, concurrency, and availability
>   of InnoDB tables during DDL (primarily ALTER TABLE) operations. See
>   Section 14.11, “InnoDB and Online DDL” for details.
>
> The details vary according to the type of operation. In some cases,
>   the table can be modified concurrently while the ALTER TABLE is in
>   progress. The operation might be able to be performed without doing a
>   table copy, or using a specially optimized type of table copy. Space
>   usage is controlled by the innodb_online_alter_log_max_size
>   configuration option.

It lets you adjust the balance between performance and concurrency during the DDL operation, by choosing whether to block access to the table entirely (LOCK=EXCLUSIVE clause), allow queries but not DML (LOCK=SHARED clause), or allow full query and DML access to the table (LOCK=NONE clause). When you omit the LOCK clause or specify LOCK=DEFAULT, MySQL allows as much concurrency as possible depending on the type of operation.

Performing changes in-place where possible, rather than creating a new copy of the table, avoids temporary increases in disk space usage and I/O overhead associated with copying the table and reconstructing secondary indexes.

see [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual -> InnoDB and Online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl.html) for more info.

It seems that online DDL also available in MariaDB

> Alternatively you can use ALTER ONLINE TABLE to ensure that your ALTER
>   TABLE does not block concurrent operations (takes no locks). It is
>   equivalent to LOCK=NONE.

[MariaDB KB about ALTER TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/)

Comment: It's a shame there is no way other than votes to float this to the top, given it mostly negates all the other answers purely because they no longer reference the current version of MySQL.

Answer (score 17):

See Facebook's online schema change tool.

http://www.facebook.com/notes/mysql-at-facebook/online-schema-change-for-mysql/430801045932

Not for the faint of heart; but it will do the job.

Answer (score 14):

I recommend Postgres if that's an option.  With postgres there is essentially no downtime with the following procedures:

- [ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN (if the column can be NULL)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html#AEN57290)
- ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN
- [CREATE INDEX (must use CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY)
- DROP INDEX

Other great feature is that most DDL statements are transactional, so you could do an entire migration within a SQL transaction, and if something goes wrong, the entire thing gets rolled back.

I wrote [this](http://corner.squareup.com/2011/06/postgresql-data-is-important.html) a little bit ago, perhaps it can shed some more insight on the other merits.

Comment: Postgres still creates an exclusive lock on the alter, preventing others from reading from that table.

Comment: I disagree with the "essentially no downtime" bit. As clofresh said, ALTER TABLE grabs an exclusive lock on the table blocking all concurrent reads and writes. In my experience, for active tables most of the times you won't even get the lock (ALTER TABLE will starve). And with transactions you can easily end up with deadlocks if you're not extremely careful. Because of that I now always set downtimes when altering existing tables in Postgres.

Comment: a more detailed explanation: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/alter-table-on-live-production-databases#27156 it mentions the implications of the exclusive lock, and some ways to work around it

Comment: Yes, altering a table in postgres grabs an exclusive lock, but because the operation itself completes in milliseconds this is practically irrelevant in most cases.  I have personally added columns to hundred-million-row tables in the middle of the business day with zero resulting downtime.

Comment: You're right. I learnt that the starvation issues I had were related to a concurrent pg_dump as part of our hourly backup. One shouldn't do pg_dump on the primary/master DB.

Comment: @NoahYetter just curious, have you done `DROP COLUMN` commands, and if so, are they also about as fast as an add, or do they need to "touch" every row?

Comment: @cobbzilla Yes, DROP COLUMN is just as fast. Under the hood what it basically does is mark the column as hidden. Values that existed in that column before was dropped are still in the data files (and visible to other transactions), and will remain so unless and until you do a VACUUM FULL.

Answer (score 7):

Since you asked about other databases, here's some information about Oracle.

Adding a NULL column to an Oracle table is a very quick operation as it only updates the data dictionary.  This holds an exclusive lock on the table for a very short period of time.  It will however, invalidate any depedant stored procedures, views, triggers, etc.  These will get recompiled automatically.

From there if necessary you can create index using the ONLINE clause.  Again, only very short data dictionary locks.  It'll read the whole table looking for things to index, but does not block anyone while doing this.

If you need to add a foreign key, you can do this and get Oracle to trust you that the data is correct.  Otherwise it needs to read the whole table and validate all the values which can be slow (create your index first).

If you need to put a default or calculated value into every row of the new column, you'll need to run a massive update or perhaps a little utility program that populates the new data.  This can be slow, especially if the rows get alot bigger and no longer fit in their blocks.  Locking can be managed during this process.  Since the old versino of your application, which is still running, does not know about this column you might need a sneaky trigger or to specify a default.

From there, you can do a switcharoo on your application servers to the new version of the code and it'll keep running.  Drop your sneaky trigger.

Alternatively, you can use DBMS_REDEFINITION which is a black box designed to do this sort of thing.

All this is so much bother to test, etc that we just have an early Sunday morning outage whenever we release a major version.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot afford downtime for your database when doing application updates you should consider maintaining a two-node cluster for high availability. With a simple replication setup, you could do almost fully online structural changes like the one you suggest:

- wait for all changes to be replicated on a passive slave
- change the passive slave to be the active master
- do the structural changes to the old master
- replicate changes back from the new master to the old master
- do the master swapping again and the new app deployment simultaneously

It is not always easy but it works, usually with 0 downtime! The second node does not have to be only passive one, it can be used for testing, doing statistics or as a fallback node.
If you do not have infrastructure replication can be set up within a single machine (with two instances of MySQL).

Comment: Old master is out of the cluster or within the cluster ?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. If you are using MyISAM tables, to my best understanding they only do table locks - there are no record locks, they just try to keep everything hyperfast through simplicity. (Other MySQL tables operate differently.) In any case, you can copy the table to another table, alter it, and then switch them, updating for differences.

This is such a massive alteration that I doubt any DBMS would support it. It's considered a benefit to be able to do it with data in the table in the first place.

Comment: InnoDB uses row locks - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html

Comment: Yeah, MySQL is the aberration. That's why I was specific about "standard" tables.

Comment: You wrote - standard MySQL tables only do table locks - which is incorrect.

Comment: How do you interpret this about MyISAM (i.e. MySQL standard) tables from the page you quoted? "MySQL uses table-level locking for MyISAM and MEMORY tables, page-level locking for BDB tables, and row-level locking for InnoDB tables."

Comment: some storage engines use row level locking, and some use table level locking. There is no standard storage engine (maybe you meant the default in phpMyAdmin...)

Comment: So you're new to MySQL? MyISAM is what's installed unless you change it. It's by far the most widely used. What definition would you associate with "Standard"?

Comment: All the mentioned storage engines are installed by default.. You determine the storage engine with the table creation query.
I've been using MySQL for over 7 years to answer your question.

Comment: OK. I'll concede whatever your point is - your experience is different and perhaps more legitimate than mine. What would you like me to change to correct my answer?

Comment: The sentence about the locks is completely incorrect, you should drop it

Comment: I don't think it's completely inaccurate; I've clarified it. Perhaps we can at least agree to respectfully differ. How do you read this re MyISAM; "The binary portable storage engine that is the default storage engine used by MySQL." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: By saying standard you implied more than the default storage engine - rather that it was "standard". I use InnoDB as the standard storage engine in my applications, and so do most production MySQL databases that require transactions. Removed my downvote since you cleared it up.

Comment: @Eran, I'm reminded how critical it is for database architects and developers to be precise and unambiguous. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still reading this or happens to come here, this is the big benefit of using a NoSQL database system like mongodb. I had the same issue dealing with altering the table to either add columns for additional features or indexes on a large table with millions of rows and high writes. It would end up locking for a very long time so doing this on the LIVE database would frustrate our users. On small tables you can get away with it.

I hate the fact that we have to "design our tables to avoid altering them". I just don't think that works in today's website world. You can't predict how people will use your software that's why you rapidly change things based on user feedback. With mongodb, you can add "columns" at will with no downtime. You don't really even add them, you just insert data with new columns and it does it automatically.

Worth checking out: www.mongodb.com

Comment: MySQL is still used in many systems, so the question is really about how to achieve a schema change in SQL RDBMS, even though I'm an ardent NoSQL supporter too.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution...

Other solution could be, add a another table with primary key of the original table, along with your new column.

Populate your primary key onto the new table and populate values for new column in your new table, and modify your query to join this table for select operations and you also need to insert, update separately for this column value.

When you able to get downtime, you can alter the original table, modify your DML queries and drop your new table created earlier

Else, you may go for clustering method, replication, pt-online-schema tool from percona

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely try `pt-online-schema-change`. I have been using this tool to do migrations on AWS RDS with multiple slaves and it has worked very well for me. I wrote an elaborate blog post on how to do that which might be helpful for you.

Blog: http://mrafayaleem.com/2016/02/08/live-mysql-schema-changes-with-percona/

Answer (score 1):

Using the Innodb plugin, ALTER TABLE statements which only add or drop secondary indexes can be done "quickly", i.e. without rebuilding the table.

Generally speaking however, in MySQL, any ALTER TABLE involves rebuilding the entire table which can take a very long time (i.e. if the table has a useful amount of data in it).

You really need to design your application so that ALTER TABLE statements do not need to be done regularly; you certainly don't want any ALTER TABLE done during normal running of the application unless you're prepared to wait or you're altering tiny tables.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is going to be "No". You're changing the structure of the table which potentially will require a lot of updates" and I definitely agree with that. If you expect to be doing this often, then I'll offer an alternative to "dummy" columns - use `VIEW`s instead of tables for `SELECT`ing data. IIRC, changing the definition of a view is relatively lightweight and the indirection through a view is done when the query plan is compiled. The expense is that you would have to add the column to a new table and make the view `JOIN` in the column.

Of course this only works if you can use foreign keys to perform cascading of deletes and whatnot. The other bonus is that you can create a new table containing a combination of the data and point the view to it without disturbing client usage.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend one of two approaches:

1. Design your database tables with the potential changes in mind.  For example, I've worked with Content Management Systems, which change data fields in content regularly.  Instead of building the physical database structure to match the initial CMS field requirements, it is much better to build in a flexible structure.  In this case, using a blob text field (varchar(max) for example) to hold flexible XML data.  This makes structural changes very less frequent.  Structural changes can be costly, so there is a benefit to cost here as well.
2. Have system maintenance time.  Either the system goes offline during changes (monthly, etc), and the changes are scheduled during the least heavily trafficked time of the day (3-5am, for example).  The changes are staged prior to production rollout, so you will have a good fixed window estimate of downtime.

2a. Have redundant servers, so that when the system has downtime, the whole site does not go down.  This would allow you to "roll" your updates out in a staggered fashion, without taking the whole site down.

Options 2 and 2a may not be feasible; they tend to be only for larger sites/operations.  They are valid options, however, and I have personally used all of the options presented here.

Comment: In option 1, we can add a generic field called "other" of type JSON and use that for any fields that we want to add.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Postgres and MySQL in this regard is that in Postgres it doesn't re-creates a table, but modifies data dictionary which is similar to Oracle. Therefore, the operation is fast, while it's still requires to allocate an exclusive DDL table lock for very short time as stated above by others.

In MySQL the operation will copy data to a new table while blocking transactions, which has been main pain for MySQL DBAs prior to v. 5.6.

The good news is that since MySQL 5.6 release the restriction has been [mostly lifted](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) and you now can enjoy the true power of the MYSQL DB.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to link to a reference regarding a change in MySql 5.6, but it didn't work.  Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

As SeanDowney has mentioned, `pt-online-schema-change` is one of the best tools to do what you have described in the question here. I recently did a lot of schema changes on a live DB and it went pretty well. You can read more about it on my blog post here: http://mrafayaleem.com/2016/02/08/live-mysql-schema-changes-with-percona/.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy columns are a good idea if you can predict their type (and make them nullable). Check how your storage engine handles nulls.

MyISAM will lock everything if you even mention a table name in passing, on the phone, at the airport.  It just does that...

That being said, locks aren't really that big a deal; as long as you are not trying to add a default value for the new column to every row, but let it sit as null, and your storage engine is smart enough not to go writing it, you should be ok with a lock that is only held long enough to update the metadata.  If you do try to write a new value, well, you are toast.

Comment: I tried adding a NULL column to an InnoDB table and it had to rebuild the entire table; not a simple "update the metadata" operation.

Comment: I think the idea was to include extra, nullable, columns in the database when it's designed, so that if a new feature is required one can "add" new column simply by starting to use it.  It won't have a nice name, but if the data type was correctly chosen/predicted it should work.

Answer (score 0):

TokuDB can add/drop columns and add indexes "hot", the table is fully available throughout the process.  It is available via www.tokutek.com

Answer (score -8):

Not really.

You ARE altering the underlying structure of the table, after all, and that's a bit of information that's quite important to the underlying system. You're also (likely) moving much of the data around on disk.

If you plan on doing this a lot, you're better off simply padding the table with "dummy" columns that are available for future use.

Comment: Padding a table with dummy columns seems to be a really bad idea.

Comment: This is probably the worst idea i've ever heard