# Forcing an alter table on MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking

I'm trying to add a column to a live database, that's constantly being accessed:-

```
ALTER TABLE `projects` ADD COLUMN `cTime` INT(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `session`
```

It ALWAYS hangs. This is a MyISAM table and I'm guessing it's trying to lock the table. I've tried IGNORE, but is there anyway to force this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a double null in you statement

```
ALTER TABLE `projects` ADD COLUMN `cTime` INT(30) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `session`
```

Comment: Found this link: [Alter a table without locking the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463677/alter-table-without-locking-the-table), hope it helps