# How wide-columns databases achieve dynamic columns on the storage layout?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

As known, in relational databases, when adding a new column, data must be reallocated ([ALTER TABLE without locking the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463677/alter-table-without-locking-the-table)) to maintain a single row contiguous on disk.

[image]

I would like to understand how this is achieved on wide-columns storages such as Cassandra, which are sparses and can handle lots of dynamic columns insertions (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3 (Dynamic Column family))

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cassandra adding a Column is adding a bit like adding row in relational database. You can even delete a column for a specific row:

```
delete first_name from user where user_id='abcd';
```

In CQL, `alter table` doesn't modify all rows, in short it just modifies the schema dictionary which describe tables (look at tables prefixed `schema_` in the `system` keyspace). This changes only CQL parsing (the new column is now recognized) and interpretation (`select * from user` meaning is changed).

When you drop a column, data doesn't appear anymore in query results yet it is still present in SSTables. The data will be removed (and space freed) during a future compaction (like tombstones).