# Changing a column type from integer to string

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration

Using PostgreSQL, what's the command to migrate an `integer` column type to a `string` column type?

Obviously I'd like to preserve the data, by converting the old integer data to strings.

Comment: Does postgresql have the `TO_CHAR` function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can convert from `INTEGER` to `CHARACTER VARYING` out-of-the-box, all you need is `ALTER TABLE` query chaning column type:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9ded/2)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (col INT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1), (10), (100);
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col TYPE CHARACTER VARYING(10);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT col, pg_typeof(col) FROM tbl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9ded/2/0)**:

```
| col |         pg_typeof |
|-----|-------------------|
|   1 | character varying |
|  10 | character varying |
| 100 | character varying |
```

Comment: A note about foreign keys: If the column you're trying to change from `int` to `character varying` is the target of a foreign key constraint, you'll have to drop the foreign key constraint before you'll be able to run the `ALTER TABLE` statement in this answer. You'll also need to alter the type of the column referencing the original column, and then you can recreate the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a four step process:

1. Create a new string column. name it temp for now. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-alter.html for details
2. Set the string column. something like `update myTable set temp=cast(intColumn as text)` see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html for more interesting number->string conversions

*Make sure everything in temp looks the way you want it.*

3. Remove your old integer column. Once again, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-alter.html for details
4. Rename temp to the old column name. Again: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-alter.html

This assumes you can perform the operation while no clients are connected; offline. If you need to make this (drastic) change in an online table, take a look at setting up a new table with triggers for live updates, then swap to the new table in an atomic operation. see [ALTER TABLE without locking the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463677/alter-table-without-locking-the-table)